# Android Binding layout id

Tags: android, android-databinding

I want to use the "new" data binding library to bind an header layout and a menu to my NavigationView.

I tried like this :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@{navigationViewModel.HeaderLayout}"
    app:menu="@{navigationViewModel.Menu}" />
```

With my viewmodel like this :

```
public class NavigationViewModel extends BaseObservable {

    public @IdRes int getHeaderLayout(){
        return 0;
    }

    public @MenuRes int getMenu(){
        return 0;
    }

}
```

But I got this exception:

> Error:(41, 33) Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:headerLayout' with parameter type int.

What kind of type should I use so?

Comment: check this: https://github.com/evant/binding-collection-adapter/issues/7

Comment: do you try with "@{navigationViewModel.headerLayout} with headerLayout in lowerCase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to get this error but now I fixed it using `@BindingAdapter`.

```
@BindingAdapter(value = "app:headerLayout", requireAll = false)
public static void inflateHeaderLayout(NavigationView navigationView, @LayoutRes int layoutRes) {
    navigationView.inflateHeaderView(layoutRes);
}
```

And the rest is your set data code.

According to [this](https://realm.io/news/data-binding-android-boyar-mount/) presentation, they called it Automagic Attributes while some custom attributes the Data Binding be able to find their method by using prefix `set` ( maybe :) ). For example,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:scrimColor="@{@color/scrim}"/>
```

Then no error because

```
drawerLayout.setScrimColor(
  resources.getColor(R.color.scrim))
```

But in the case of `app:headerLayout`, there's no `setHeaderLayout()` method in `NavigationView`. So we need to create anbinding adapter for that attribute.